# Add Math and scientific elements and symbols to Tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have a TinyMCE WYSWYG editor and is there any ways, plugins available to add scientific and mathematical symbols and expressions.
I have found MathQuil and it seems to be not working and repository is not updated in years.
Is there any workAround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed very late that your post included a `tinymce-4` tag. The solution I've created is using TinyMCE 5 (https://github.com/dallasclark/tinymce-mathquill-plugin).

Feel free to use this as a guide to create a TinyMCE 4 plugin if required, otherwise feel free to use the code to suit your needs for TinyMCE 5.

*The solution was a quick draft, and "might be" improved over time*

---

Separate note, I would highly recommend migrating from TinyMCE 4 to TinyMCE 5. Please refer to Tiny's blog post "[How to migrate from TinyMCE 4 to TinyMCE 5](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-migrate-from-tinymce-4-to-tinymce-5)" for instructions on how to migrate.